# Is there any way of "swapping" GPU memory in tensorflow?

Tags: memory, tensorflow

I am training a large model which exceeds the GPU memory (more than 11 GB). I am wondering if there are any way in tensorflow to swap the GPU memory into main memory. Some loss of efficiency is acceptable. Training the model fully on CPU solves the problem of memory but is too slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466255/is-there-a-workaround-for-running-out-of-memory-on-gpu-with-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

There are some classes in tensorflow to create networks with a *swap_memory* argument.

e.g. for RNN you can use **tf.nn.dynamic_rnn** or **tf.nn.raw_rnn**

There is also a more generic looping class **tf.while_loop** with this argument.

But there is imho no general option for using memory swapping.

Just take a look at tensorflow.org and use its search function. You can find relevant classes using *swap_memory*